# How to create an docker-container with mount points using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, containers

for my Unittests I want to start for every test one docker container using python.
I want to mount the repository into the container, so that the dependencies are working.
Here is my code:

```py
repository = "d:/Test"
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(
            image=docker_image,
            detach=True,
            volumes={repository: {'bind': '/repository', 'mode': 'rw'}}
        )
```

I got this error:

```
("invalid volume specification: 'd:/Test:/repository:rw'")
```

The folder is located on my D-Partition on Windows. I already tried D:\ d:/, or everything else.

Comment: Looks like it is windows file url, should it be `r"D:\Test"`?

Comment: Already tried, not working.